# When I try to copy the files by Post-build Actions " Send build artifacts over SSH" then I got the error

Tags: jenkins

```
    Source files :- /home/mbox140/Desktop/qtworkspace/mbox_gui/Debug.tar.gz
    Remove prefix :- /home/mbox140/Desktop/qtworkspace/mbox_gui/
    Remote directory :- /mbox140/deployment/mbox_gui/
    Exec command :- blank
```

`enter code here` Started by user Vikash
    Building on master in workspace           /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Copy_Mbox_Gui_Files/workspace
    next nodes: []SSH: Connecting from host [mbox140-Vikash]
    SSH: Connecting with configuration [mbox140] ...
    SSH: Disconnecting configuration [mbox140] ...
    SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
    Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: I don't think it is clear from this question what you are doing. Would you edit it to add (much) more detail please?